# Mysql join with multiple case statements in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. One is `engine4_users` and other is `engine4_user_fields_values`. The `engine4_users` table contains `id, email, password,displayname`. It has `one to many` relation with `engine4_user_fields_values` table. The `engine4_user_fields_values` table looks like

[image]

Where `item_id` is the `user_id` of the users table. Now as you can see, in this table field_id can have many values too against one item id.

Now I want to select data from both of these table in such a way that some times I need value of `value` column and sometimes I need to put `value` column in where condition based on field_id. 
For example see my query

```
SELECT 
`eu`.`user_id`, `eu`.`displayname`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
                   CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 19 THEN eufv.value END
                 ) AS city,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 15 THEN eufv.value END
        )AS interests

FROM 
     `engine4_users` AS `eu`
    INNER JOIN 
     `engine4_user_fields_values` AS `eufv` 
    ON 
    eu.user_id = eufv.item_id 
    WHERE 
     (eu.username LIKE '%hameed%' OR eu.email LIKE '%hameed%' OR eu.displayname LIKE '%hameed%') 
   GROUP BY 
`eu`.`user_id`;
```

This query get data group by user and get values of field_id 15 an 16 as comma separated. Now I want to put more where conditions on this second table to filter out the result.

For example I want to put condition on field_id 6 which is birthdate that age of the person is in some range, and field_id 5 to where value is 3. But when I put following query

```
SELECT 
`eu`.`user_id`, `eu`.`displayname`, 

GROUP_CONCAT(
                   CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 19 THEN eufv.value END
                 ) AS city,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 15 THEN eufv.value END
        )AS interests
    FROM 
     `engine4_users` AS `eu`
    INNER JOIN 
   `engine4_user_fields_values` AS `eufv` 
    ON 
   eu.user_id = eufv.item_id 
    WHERE 
    (eu.username LIKE '%hameed%' OR eu.email LIKE '%hameed%' OR eu.displayname LIKE '%hameed%') 
   AND 
   (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 6 THEN eufv.`value` END ) / 365) >= '20') 
   AND 
   (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 6 THEN eufv.`value` END ) / 365) <= '29') 
  GROUP BY 
`eu`.`user_id`;
```

This query gives result but in this case I don't get values of columns city and interests. They come empty in resultset. And If I put one more condition in where clause which is

```
AND ((CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 5 THEN eufv.`value` END)  = '3')
```

which is good and map with the record. But in this case the result set comes empty.

I have tried to explain my problem as much as I can. So please guide me how can I write this query or let me know if I am unable to convey my problem.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You are using CASE WHEN without an ELSE. So for instance the following condition is false for all eufv.field_id <> 6, because the CASE evaluates to NULL which is not >= 20.

```
(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 6 THEN eufv.`value` END ) / 365) >= '20') 
AND
```

Secondly: of course, when narrowing your criteria you get less records. Maybe you would like all engine4_users and only add data from engine4_user_fields_values when your criteria is met? That would be an outer join:

```
FROM `engine4_users` AS `eu`
LEFT JOIN `engine4_user_fields_values` AS `eufv` 
ON 
  eu.user_id = eufv.item_id AND 
  (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),CASE WHEN eufv.field_id = 6 THEN eufv.`value` END ) / 365) >= '20') 
  ...
WHERE 
  (eu.username LIKE '%hameed%' OR eu.email LIKE '%hameed%' OR eu.displayname LIKE '%hameed%')
```

Make sure you have all conditions for table ne4_user_fields_values in the ON clause instead of the WHERE clause when outer-joining.

Comment: What will be in else statement in my case? And I don't want all users by `Left Join`. I want only users meeting criteria.

Comment: Even using left join as you suggested, I get those columns empty again

Comment: In the ELSE part you would put some value that meets the criteria, for instance DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 YEAR); Or do it outside: (eufv.field_id <> 6 OR FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), eufv.`value`) / 365) >= '20')